# Can't push application to Bluemix after cflinuxfs2 removed

Tags: stack, ibm-cloud

I encountered an problem when push application to bluemix.

When I used the following command:

```
bluemix app push cam-dev
```

It told me to define build stack:

> The app is invalid: Must specify either a buildpack_url or an admin_buildpack_name

Then I use the following command to use stack cflinuxfs2:

```
bluemix app push cam-dev -s cflinuxfs2
```

It failed with following errors:

> **ERROR** Unsupported stack
>                       See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/stacks.html for more info
>
> Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 1

Then I see the cflinuxfs2 stack is no longer supported. The message tells me to update my app stack to cflinuxfs3 by pushing it again. I did it but it also failed with the following message:

> FAILED
>
> Stack cflinuxfs3 not found

I don't know what I can do to update it to cflinuxfs3. I used `cf stacks` and found there are only 2 available stacks:

> lucid64      Ubuntu 10.04 on x86-64
>
> cflinuxfs2   Ubuntu 14.04.2 trusty

Comment: Can you explain how to reproduce this problem from an empty directory.  For example could you provide a github repository that I can start from to reproduce?

Comment: Your document references Cloud Foundry. Their documentation might not match IBM Cloud. Use IBM documentation so that you are using supported features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by the bluemix has not yet upgrade to cflinuxfs3 but the build pack for cflinuxfs2 has been removed. I found a solution for it:
Add the following lines to manifest.yml:
buildpacks:
   - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack#v1.6.56

Or you can use following command:
bluemix app push cam-dev -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack#v1.6.56